# What stops stolen software from offering a valid license?

Tags: copyright, software, licensing, eula, online-piracy

A common pattern in software distribution is to have an installer program that pops up and offers the user a license to the software, and prompts the user to accept it. This End User License Agreement will almost always include a term explicitly granting the user the right to install and use the software.

I've never seen a license agreement like this make that license conditional on having *actually paid for* the software. Sometimes they will mention that one needs to e.g. "activate" software against a server or enter a product key for the license to apply, but even in those cases it doesn't seem common to stipulate that e.g. the key must have been *purchased by you*.

What if the user gets their installer by downloading it for free from an unauthorized distributor, instead of by paying for a copy from someone licensed to distribute them?

If the user runs the unmodified installer and it immediately offers the user a license from the software author, and the user accepts it and complies with it, **do they end up with a properly licensed installation?**

If not, why not? Why would the software author's automated offer of a license not "count"? Or are terms in the license handling this situation much more common than I realize? Or has the author managed to revoke the user's license without knowing about its existence?

Comment: Isn’t it a temporary evaluation licence in many cases of installers?

Comment: Sometimes, especially if the application has its own internal way to take a key or to activate, but many installers seem to offer a full license.

Comment: Where did this "unauthorized distributor" get the license from?

Comment: @interfect I’m curious what some examples would be, and what the T&C actually say

Comment: The unauthorized destributor would be distributing a copy of the whole disk/installer, which would include the license. Presumably they copied it from a purchased copy without authorization. One example document is the Blizzard EULA at https://www.blizzard.com/en-us/legal/fba4d00f-c7e4-4883-b8b9-1b4500a402ea/blizzard-end-user-license-agreement which says you get a license and notes that you "may" need to actually buy some games before you can physically play them.

Comment: Here's another license example which says that as soon as I "access" or "download" this game, I have a license to install it on one computer: https://store.steampowered.com/eula/1611910_eula_0

Comment: And here's an example of how a document like this might be presented by desktop software distributed as a disk or an installer program: https://int64software.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/overlaps-1.2-inst-1.png

Comment: @interfect - The "license" is generally held at the publisher. I have a very nice CAD program. $$$$. The "license" is a combination of my email and the specific code they associate with that email. Joe.random@gmail.com + 12345ABcd. This data is held at the mothership. If I "sell" that installer package plus that email/SN combination, the publisher is going to notice hat it is being installed and accessed from multiple locations at the same time. They WILL kill off one or all of those licenses. I can absolutely sell it, but I can no longer continue to use it.

Comment: @interfect The Blizzard EULA is for their gaming platform, not for their games; they say *"To play Games, you may need to add a Game license to an Account"*, clearly indicating that the games have their own licenses, so you'd need to look at the license for a specific game for the rest of the details. The Frontier EULA even more clearly states, *"To Use the Game you are required to pay a fee."* If you actually read the full EULA of any commercial software you will find that they actually *do* state you have to pay.

Comment: @Herohtar good catch! I missed that point in the Frontier agreement. Looks like they thought of this.

Comment: "What if the user gets their installer by downloading it for free from an unauthorized distributor, ". Then the so-called license is a forgery, and has no effect. The fact that someone tells you you have a license doesn't mean that you actually have one; they can be lying.

Comment: @MichaelKay if the license offer is a forgery in that case, would the user be able to then useor copy the software to the extent allowed under fair use, without having to comply with any terms of service contracts the software presents, because those contract offers would also be forgeries?

Comment: What are you really Asking, please?

How could you doubt that stolen software was… uh… 'stolen' or that necessarily meant nothing 'offered by' it could be 'valid'… unless you have a special definition of 'valid'?

Have you?

Comment: @interfect If the license is a forgery then they are using the software without a license and are therefore in breach of copyright laws. Whether they are committing an offence if they do that unknowingly is a question for a lawyer. If there are things the user can do without breaching copyright (e.g because of "fair use") then the status of the license doesn't come into it: a license is only needed to do things that you wouldn't be able to do otherwise.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Really I'm trying to wrap my head around questions of agency in software, and when things done by code can or cannot be taken as being actually done by people. So I wanted to know if a defect in the "chain of title" or chain of licensing for software would mean that the software is no longer allowed to offer licenses or contracts on behalf of its author. I use the word "stolen" here as shorthand for something like "used or copied without a license or a statutory right to do so"; you generally can't actually make off with intellectual property.

Comment: Really you might do better trying to drop all the rest, and wrap your head around how 'fake' or 'stolen' or 'theft' will always override anything that might have applied to a legitimate sale.

How could any question of agency, detail of the software or suggestion that things done by code were taken as done by people be relevant?

You seem to be using a special definition of ‘stolen’ that might not include ’falsehood’ or ‘theft.’

Can you say how that works, and how it doesn’t invalidate the idea of a thief offering a ’valid license’?

Comment: I think I wrote "stolen" about copyright, when I really should have used "pirated" or something similar. I am interested in the case of boxed software shoplifted from a store, but also in the case of e.g. freeware that is only allowed to be distributed from the author's site being rehosted elsewhere, or torrented AAA games, or even the case of borrowing a CD with the permission of its owner and then trying to get a second licensed install out of it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> I've never seen a license agreement like this make that license conditional on having actually paid for the software.

Careful reading of license agreements shows that this isn't accurate. Commercial license agreements do not grant rights to illegally acquired software.

[Microsoft Windows EULA](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Windows/10/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_10_English.htm)

> Applicability. This agreement applies to the Windows software that is preinstalled on your device, or acquired from a retailer and installed by you...

So versions downloaded illegally aren't covered.

[Adobe General Terms](https://www.adobe.com/legal/terms.html)

> License. Subject to your compliance with the Terms **and applicable law**, we hereby grant you a non-exclusive, limited, revocable right for you to install...
>
> ...
>
> 11.2 Termination by Us. Unless stated in the Additional Terms, we may at any time immediately terminate or suspend your right to use and access the Services and Software, without refunds for any pre-paid fees, if in Adobe's sole discretion:
>
> ...
>
> (B) you fail to make the timely payment of fees for the Services and Software, if any;

[Autodesk License](https://download.autodesk.com/us/FY17/Suites/LSA/en-us/lsa.html)

> 1.1 License Grant. Subject to and conditioned on Licensee’s continuous compliance with this Agreement **and payment of the applicable fees**, Autodesk grants Licensee a nonexclusive, nonsublicensable, nontransferable, limited license to Install and Access the Licensed Materials
>
> ...
>
> 2.1.1 No License Granted; Unauthorized Activities. The parties acknowledge and agree that, notwithstanding anything to the contrary in this Agreement, no license is granted (whether expressly, by implication or otherwise) under this Agreement (and this Agreement expressly excludes any right) (a)... (b) **to any Autodesk Materials that Licensee did not acquire lawfully** or that Licensee acquired in violation of or in a manner inconsistent with this Agreement,

Comment: This is the correct answer. The OP likely has not closely read many EULAs. Even the ones linked to in the comments on the question mention payment or additional licenses being required.

Comment: I'm even more confused now. Microsoft Windows is downloadable straight from their website, no retailing needed. Surely a good can't be considered retailed, if no account is made, no payment collected, and is given away to everyone as they please?

Comment: @tuskiomi You can download it, but you have no right to install or use the software without a license acquired from retail or with your computer purchase. This is no different from the fact that you can't install multiple copies of traditionally-distributed software from the same media without buying additional licenses.

Comment: @user71659 ok.. that's disingenuous at best since the software lets you install it without any license. Microsoft put in extra effort to let you do so as well...

Comment: from the Microsoft example "acquired from a retailer and installed by you" if the retailer just pirates software how does this formulation cover the legality?

Comment: @tuskiomi I think you're confused by the computer manufacturer's preinstalled license key. Windows pulls it from the system firmware and uses it automatically, so it only appears there isn't any license validation. If you have a homebuilt system or a pre-built with Linux/FreeDOS (typically servers), then you have to enter a CD key manually. Enterprises can also set up license servers that are automatically discovered. In all cases, the key is automatically activated over the Internet, or else Windows goes into restricted functionality mode.

Comment: So in theory a poorly drafted license agreement would grant a license to anyone who accepted it, whether they actually purchased the software or not, but in practice almost all agreements are properly drafted to prohibit this, somewhere in the middle of the license terms.

Comment: @user71659 No, I'm not. presently, you may install windows 7, 10 and 11 without an internet connection, and without entering any key, on a hand-built system, without any modifications to the software, and with all core functionality in tact.

Answer (score 21):

**A computer can’t enter into a contract**

A EULA is a contract between the software company (not the computer) and the end user. If the software is obtained in a manner authorized by the publisher, then the publisher has extended the offer, and the end user accepts.

Pirated software does not come from the publisher or an authorized agent of the publisher. It cannot be binding on the publisher because they were never a party to the contract.

Let’s say there are three parties, A, B, and C. A and B write and sign a contract that says “B and C agree to (contract),” but C doesn’t sign it. A and B cannot enforce this contract on C, even though the contract references C, because C was never a party to the contract.

**Also**

Pirating software is always a crime, even if you have not accepted the EULA. By copying the installer to your computer, you have already committed a crime. Even if you could somehow argue that you got a valid license later, this does not erase the crime you already committed.

Comment: This is generally a sound analysis. I'd just add the nuance that in the context of whether an arbitration clause in a license is binding, that in some circumstances a non-signatory is bound by arbitration clause in the contract in circumstances where other contractual terms would ordinarily not be binding.

Comment: "Pirating software is always a crime." Is not universally true. For example, [software piracy is legal in Belarus under certain conditions](https://deadline.com/2023/01/belarus-legalizes-piracy-of-content-from-unfriendly-nations-1235215833/). Whether or not it's always [ethical](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/cs181/projects/software-piracy/ethical.html) is a different matter.

Comment: "*Pirating software is always a crime...*" Seems tautological. Keep in mind we have an international audience and laws will vary. Would you tag your answer with the jurisdiction(s) your answer covers? I'd be interested to see the law that makes mere possession of an installer illegal.

Comment: Software piracy isn't always a crime. Sometimes it's only a civil matter: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/87442/where-is-the-line-between-civil-and-criminal-breach-of-copyright

Comment: Piracy is defined as "the unauthorized use or reproduction of another's work". Does that not mean it is a crime by definition or does it depend on the punishment?

Comment: @Parrotmaster: Doing things without authorization isn't always a crime.

Comment: @Parrotmaster Non-criminal copyright infringement is a _civil wrong_. Remedies will be pursued through the [civil litigation process](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/45433/criminal-v-civil-litigation-what-are-the-differences) rather than criminal litigation. Among other differences, you can't go to jail in a civil case; if found responsible (instead of guilty), the resolution can be paying money and/or an injunction which stops you from continuing infringement.

Comment: I often see printed sheet music with the legend "Copying is theft". I often feel they should relinquish their right to any remedy as a penalty for making such a false claim. Whether or not it's a crime, it's certainly not theft.